# How to check If a file is present in another file or not?

Tags: java

I'm writing a code to print files that are there in a given file, my code looks like  this:

```
try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().endsWith(".svn")) {
                displayDirectoryContents(file);
            } else {
                mMap.put(file.getCanonicalPath(), file.getCanonicalPath());
                System.out.println( mMap.get(file.getCanonicalPath()));
```

Now, I've to compare the output of this code i.e. the file paths, if they're present in a separate text file or not, by reading and comparing with that file. Please help with your inputs as I'm new to JAVA.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you read both files and compare what you read.  To speed this up you can compare the lengths first.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did file comparisons in java using google's [diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/) which worked quite well.

The documentation was not great so I ended up reading the test cases for usage. Also the binaries weren't on maven central so I included the java sources (and license) in my own source code.

Answer (score 0):

you cant check whether a file exists in another file. You need to check whether contents of a file exists in another file.

Comment: My code here only prints the file names stored in a particular directory and prints them out. So, in that case I only need to match whether that file name is present in another text file or not. This text file will only contain some file names.